# EF 6 How to use multi level include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

```
var tickets = db.Tickets
                .Include(x => x.CreatedBy)
                .Include(x => x.Currency)
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.Trip))
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.Trip).Select(t => t.Carrier)) // ERROR 
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.Trip).Select(t => t.TripCities))
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.Number))
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.CityFrom))
                .Include(x => x.DepartureTrips.Select(t => t.CityTo))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.Trip))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.Trip).Select(t => t.Carrier))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.Trip).Select(t => t.TripCities))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.Number))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.CityFrom))
                .Include(x => x.ReturnTrips.Select(t => t.CityTo))
                .AsNoTracking()
                .AsQueryable();
```

How use include 3 level and more?
Need to do only with Include (). Lazy load will not be used (too long query time)

Comment: You might want to check out `ThenInclude`

Comment: EF 6 doesn't have ThenInclude